# iOS Newsstand app background mode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, newsstand

Does Apple still support Newsstand apps? I searched a lot but I can't find any tutorial or a demo for such an app with NewsstandKit.

If this is not used anymore, why does the Newsstand background mode still exist & where can I use it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you looking to develop a Newsstand app?

Comment: Hi Nimesh, no I was reading about background modes, so I just want to know the use of this mode.

Comment: Please share a link to the document.